# How to keep vector pattern when exporting from Inkscape to PDF or SVG?

Tags: inkscape, export

I created an image in Inkscape that incorporates a custom line pattern of diagonal lines and looks like this:
[image: Image with custom pattern as seen in Inkscape]

Now I want to export this image as vector graphic in PDF format. However when I am using Inkscapes "Save As..." and choose PDF the result looks like this:
[image: Result after export to PDF]

I also tried to export the graphic to SVG format. However there the result looks like this:
[image: Result after export to SVG]

So here some kind of pattern seems to be present, but obviously not the original one.

Is there a way to export an SVG image without loosing the pattern effect like above?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately, I can't replicate the problem. In Inkscape 0.92, objects with pattern fills work when saved as PDF or SVG without any issues.  What are you using to view the PDFs or SVGs?

Comment: Can you maybe share the svg file?

Comment: And Inkscape version and operating system would be useful, too. If you're not on 0.92.4, you should be.

Comment: You are all right! This seems to be a version issue. I just tried in a newer Inkscape version and everything works like expected.